# Cannot connect to Counter Strike 1.6 LAN over WiFi

Tags: counter-strike

I have a network of a few computers connected over wired LAN, and they are all able to play Counter Strike. But connecting a laptop to the network via WiFi just doesn't work. The problem is that I cant find the server from the laptop.

I don't think the problem is network related, I can access files of the other computers on the LAN network, via WiFi. It shouldn't have anything to do with the router configuration because it works on one laptop but not the rest.

How do I configure the laptop to connect to the Counterstrike server over WiFi?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about connecting a laptop to Wifi.  That is not gaming specific, so it does not belong here.

Comment: Is the WiFi network from the same router as the LAN? Can your computer see any of the others on the LAN? Most importantly, is this question really about connecting CS rather than connecting your computer? (Otherwise, I might try SuperUser.SE)

Comment: I have experienced this with 3 Xbox 360 runnning on the LAN and one trying to connect via wifi. Try hosting with the WiFi P.C. I would possibly suggest Static IP. Meaning addresses won't be random and also on the P.C install(If your savvy with this) under network settings(properties), protocol; Lan( I'll double check that). Running out of time to edit post.

Comment: Make sure Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) and Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6) are installed on all the P.C's. Keep in mind File and printer Sharing should probably be on. I'm using a restricted P.C at the moment and can't look in to the administrator settings, though from my experience installing these protolcols and having a static(fixed I.P) could fix this.

Comment: Lastly, could also be port forwarding.(Router settings, BACKUP first.)

Comment: @Frank please check the edit.

Comment: It's still a bit confusing to me.  You say that your laptop doesn't find the Counter Strike server but another laptop can.  Are both laptops connecting via WiFi?  Have you tried using a wired connection with the laptop that isn't working?

Comment: The determination here is whether or not the laptop you need help with is on your network.  If it is, and CS:GO can't connect, that is something we can help with.  I am unable to figure that out from what you have asked.  If you can clarify that aspect, we might have something here.

Comment: @Frank The WiFi/LAN network is good and working properly with all applications. Just that I cant connect to a counterstrike server from the laptop. I had the same problem with NFS Most Wanted that I was able to fix by editing the server.cfg file. How do I fix it for Counter Strike 1.6?